# Deploy ingress nginx with a domain in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have deployed airflow in kubernetes as is descrived in this link: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/chart

To access the airflow UI I can do:

```
 kubectl port-forward svc/airflow2-webserver 8080:8080 --namespace default
```

But I would want to expose it in a url. I found this guide:

https://godatadriven.com/blog/deploying-apache-airflow-on-azure-kubernetes-service/

In the bottom part: FQDN with Ingress controller, he installs an nginx-ingress-controller and a cert manager.

Then I create a Cluster-issuer:

```yml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: my-email@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
          podTemplate:
            spec:
              nodeSelector:
                "kubernetes.io/os": linux
```

I install the ingress-routes.yml

```yml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: airflow-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret-test2
  rules:
    - host: mydomain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: airflow2-webserver
              servicePort: 8080
```

But when I try to get my certificate:

```
kubectl describe certificate
```

```
No resources found in default namespace.
```

I have deployed everything  but I don´t know what is missing  but when I go to my domain is still not trusted

Comment: What kubernetes version are you using? Could you confirm, that you have annotation `"kubernetes.io/os": linux` in at least one on your nodes? Your cluster is on `Azure` or you only followed tutorial on azure?

Comment: Azure kubernetes service. Version: 1.16.13. OS type: Linux

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DNS [A record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/record-set/a?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-dns-record-set-a-add-record) is not pointing to your `Ingress LoadBalancer` public IP. Thus your `cert-manager issuer` is not able to validate your domain ownership from outside using http challange.

To verify you can use tool called [MXToolBox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx). In your configuration (https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3amydomain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com&run=toolpage) it's pointing to private IP.

**Solution**

To resolve this issue, you should [Add an A record to your DNS zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls#add-an-a-record-to-your-dns-zone)

```
az network dns record-set a add-record \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --zone-name MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN \
    --record-set-name '*' \
    --ipv4-address MY_EXTERNAL_IP
```